# Excel VBA function that checks if filename CONTAINS the value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that would output something like this:

If a filename in a specific folder contains (because the filename will have an additional string after a @ character), so if a filename contains the cell value AB1 then add full filename in cell AC1.

Is that doable with VBA?

Many thanks

Comment: give a proper example please

Comment: Sounds like you will want to use the like operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> Is that doable in VBA?

Sure. Here's a VBA helper function I use all the time:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal string_source As String, ByVal find_text As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod

    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If

    Contains = (InStr(1, string_source, find_text, compareMethod) <> 0)

End Function
```

I also use this one whenever I have more than one value to check for - it performs better than doing `If {check1} Or {check2} Or {check3}...` because it returns as soon as it finds a match, so `{check42}` doesn't get evaluated if `{check1}` returned `True`:

```
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal string_source As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray find_strings() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim find As String, i As Integer, found As Boolean

    For i = LBound(find_strings) To UBound(find_strings)

        find = CStr(find_strings(i))
        found = Contains(string_source, find, caseSensitive)

        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    ContainsAny = found

End Function
```

Comment: thank you so far but I'm very new to this. Where would I put the folder path and where the columns name etc.?

Comment: `string_source` would be the filename, `find_text` would be the value of cell `AB1`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim FileSpec As String, FileName As String
    Dim v As String
    FileSpec = "C:\TestFolder\2013\Fed taxes\qwerty31416.xlsm"
    ary = Split(FileSpec, "\")
    FileName = ary(UBound(ary))
    v = Range("AB1").Value
    If InStr(1, FileName, v) > 0 Then
         Range("AC1").Value = FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]