# How to set "or" in VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I set "if" with the "or" condition and give an error

`If textbox1.Text = "abc def" Or "def" Then`

I understand that I'm not writing right?
What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restate the test object

```
If textbox1.Text = "abc def" Or textbox1.Text = "def" Then
```

Comment: Thanks, if I have a lot of options I'll have to post every time "textbox1"?

Comment: How many options? If you are using this format in your test statement, then yes, the object needs to stated every time.

Comment: I can also use a variable like "or1" which is shorter for me

Comment: @slomo then make a [ContainsAny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30034704/1188513) function so that evaluation bails out as soon as one matches (`If...Then` will otherwise make every single comparison, even if the first is already `True`). But please, don't name anything `or1`... ever.

Answer (score 3):

If you have many conditions, use Select Case:

```
Select Case textbox1.Text
    Case “abc def”, “def”, “xyz”
        MsgBox “Note that multiple values may be captured here, separated by commas”
    Case “abc”
        MsgBox “Just abc”
    Case Else
        MsgBox “Everything else”
End Select
```